# draw multiple lines with canvas

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, awt, 2d

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Picture myPic = new Picture(600, 600);
    Graphics canvas = myPic.getOffScreenGraphics();

    canvas.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

    canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int heading;

    x1 = 300;
    y1 = 300;
    x2 = 300;
    y2 = 300;

    heading = 0;



    String keyboard = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter your input");

    if (keyboard != null) {
        if (keyboard.isEmpty() || keyboard.contains(" ")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    "Please enter an input",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            main(args);
        }


        int counth = 0;
        int countg = 0;
        int countPlus = 0;
        int countMinus = 0;
        int countK = 0;
        int countR = 0;
        int countG = 0;
        int countB = 0;
        int countC = 0;
        int countO = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == '+') {
                if (heading == 0) {
                    heading = 1;
                } else if (heading == 1) {
                    heading = 2;
                } else if (heading == 2) {
                    heading = 3;
                } else if (heading == 3) {
                    heading = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        countPlus++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == '-') {
                if (heading == 0) {
                    heading = 3;
                } else if (heading == 1) {
                    heading = 0;
                } else if (heading == 2) {
                    heading = 1;
                } else if (heading == 3) {
                    heading = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        countMinus++;


        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'h' || keyboard.charAt(i) == 'f') {
                if (heading == 0) {
                    counth++;
                    int k = 10 * (counth);
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2 + k);

                } else if (heading == 1) {
                    counth++;
                    int k = 10 * (counth);
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 + k, y2);
                } else if (heading == 2) {
                    counth++;
                    int k = 10 * (counth);
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2 - k);
                } else if (heading == 3) {
                    counth++;
                    int k = 10 * (counth);
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 - k, y2);
                } else if (heading > 3 || heading < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            "Your heading is greater than 3 or less than 0",
                            "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    main(args);
                }
            }

        }



        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        countK++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'R') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        countR++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'G') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
        countG++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'B') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
        countB++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
        }
        countC++;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length(); i++) {
            if (keyboard.charAt(i) == 'O') {
                canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        countO++;


        System.out.println("h = " + counth);
        System.out.println("g = " + countg);
        System.out.println("+ = " + countPlus);
        System.out.println("- = " + countMinus);
        System.out.println("K = " + countK);
        System.out.println("R = " + countR);
        System.out.println("G = " + countG);
        System.out.println("B = " + countB);
        System.out.println("C = " + countC);
        System.out.println("O = " + countO);



        myPic.repaint();
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

I'm trying to draw some lines based on user input.

The inputs are h and f for moving forward 10 pixels (both do the same thing) and + or - to change the direction the line will move 90 degrees either clockwise for + or counterclockwise for - (default is moving up).

For example, if a user inputs: "hhh" the line will move up 30 pixels.

The problem I am having is I want the user to be able to input hhh+hhh and it draw a line 30 pixels upwards then turns and draws 30 more pixels but to the right. However in my program when I input hhh+hhh it just makes one straight line 60 pixels to the right.

So my question is: how can I get it to draw a line turn when it sees either + or - in the specified direction and draw another line.

Comment: Are you missing some code here? You have never declared the "heading" variable unless I'm being blind

Comment: well i didnt include my full code but ill paste it in now. -- done

Comment: `...main(args);...` this is a really bad idea, use a loop of some kind instead

Answer (score 0):

Code completely untested but I suggest you:

Delete the two loops for + and -.

```
for(int i =0; i < keyboard.length(); i++)
  {
 if(keyboard.charAt(i) == '+')
      heading++;
 if(keyboard.charAt(i) == '-')
      heading--;

if (heading < 0)
    heading = 3;
if (heading > 3)
    heading = 0;

 if(keyboard.charAt(i) == 'h' || keyboard.charAt(i) == 'f') 
 //Snip rest of heading code here
 }
```

The issue you are having is that you are looping through the code multiple times independent of processing the line drawing code.

While this may not resolve your issue it may get you on the right track.